# Display results based on orWhere statement

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to use the orWhere stament in laravel. I'm building a small app, allowing (gaming) clans to challenge other clans, either challenging a clan directly or challenge a match placed by another clan.

A clan can create a match or when challenging another team, a match is automatically created with a boolean that the match is a challenge. A clan that challenges another clan is always the "home playing team".

I want to display all received challenges (clan challenges or match challenges and how much), for all matches and clans a user is in. So yes, both teams and matches can have multiple challenges.

With my following code, I'm trying to get all the received challenges from my database for the current user and the `$team_id_arr` contains an array with all the team ids of a user.

```
$receivedChallenges = DB::table('challenges')
->select(
    'matches.id as id',
    'matches.date as date',
    'matches.time as time',
    'challenges.id as challenge_id',
    DB::raw('count(challenges.id) as challenge_amount')
)
->leftjoin('matches', 'matches.id', '=', 'challenges.match_id')
->leftjoin('team_user as ht', 'ht.team_id', '=', 'matches.home_id')
->leftjoin('team_user as at', 'at.team_id', '=', 'matches.away_id')
->where('matches.played', '=', false)
->where('matches.planned', '=', false)
->where(function($query) use ($team_id_arr) {
    $query
    ->where('matches.challenge', '=', true)
    ->where('at.user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('challenges.opponent_id', 'matches.away_id')

    // Or where...
    ->orWhere('matches.challenge', '=', false)
    ->where('challenges.opponent_id', $team_id_arr);
})
->havingRaw('count(challenges.id) > ?', [0])
->groupBy('matches.id')
->get();
```

When a match is a challenge, the current user is in the "away playing team", thus being the `opponent_id` in the challenge table.

When a match is not a challenge, the current user is always the clan filling `opponent_id` in the challenges table.

I'm using the `havingRaw` to only display the matches that have a challenge and I want to sort everything based on the `matches.id`. Is my use of the orWhere correct, because currently the received challenges for my dummy clan aren't showing up on my page.

Comment: It would be far easier to help if you showed the table schema, small sample data, and desired result. That way we can concentrate on the thing that (I think) you’re asking— how to make the right query

Comment: Why do you need the `orWhere` clause. `matches.challenge` could be `true` or `false`. If you ask me, you don't need `matches.challenge = true`  clause if you need an orWhere to check if its `false` unless it's nullable and for that you have one where clause where `matches.challenge isnot null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL (mySQL for example),

`A AND B AND C OR D AND E`

would be interpreted as

`(A AND B AND C) OR (D AND E)`.

But since Eloquent allows queries to be constructed with commands in any order, some practices from SQL have to be translated differently.

In the case of `orWhere`, I highly recommend isolating the two alternate clauses.

```
$receivedChallenges = DB::table('challenges')
->select(
    'matches.id as id',
    'matches.date as date',
    'matches.time as time',
    'challenges.id as challenge_id',
    DB::raw('count(challenges.id) as challenge_amount')
)
->leftjoin('matches', 'matches.id', '=', 'challenges.match_id')
->leftjoin('team_user as ht', 'ht.team_id', '=', 'matches.home_id')
->leftjoin('team_user as at', 'at.team_id', '=', 'matches.away_id')
->where('matches.played', '=', false)
->where('matches.planned', '=', false)
->where(function($query) use ($team_id_arr) {
    $query->where(function($query){
        $query
        ->where('matches.challenge', '=', true)
        ->where('at.user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('challenges.opponent_id', 'matches.away_id')
    })->orWhere(function($query) use($team_id_arr){
        $query
        ->where('matches.challenge', '=', false)
        ->where('challenges.opponent_id', $team_id_arr);
    });
})
->havingRaw('count(challenges.id) > ?', [0])
->groupBy('matches.id')
->get();
```